# Failed to acquire connection to jdbc in WEBLOGIC

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic

```
SEVERE: Failed to acquire connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.24.47:1526:ORA8. Sleeping for 7000 ms. Attempts left: 5
java.sql.SQLException: Locale not recognized
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.setSessionFields(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:990)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:235)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:370)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:269)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.<init>(ConnectionHandle.java:242)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.fillConnections(PoolWatchThread.java:115)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.run(PoolWatchThread.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess either you are using some exotic locale or some problem with your locale setting. If its the later then the below solution might help you.
 Set the environment variable **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS**. The example is for Unix OS ( env setting) and locale as en-US. After setting the env try running the program again.

Unix/Linux:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Duser.country=US"
```

Windows:

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Duser.country=US
```

In case if that doesn't work you can try setting the same values for environment variable **JAVA_OPTS**  (some programs uses this variable while most uses JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS)